# How i can send few values from inputs with auto increment?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, post

I have block:

```
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="account[surname][]">
    <input type="text" name="account[address][]">
    <input type="text" name="account[phone][]">
    ...
    <input type="number" name="account[number][][1]">
    <input type="number" name="account[number][][2]">
    <input type="number" name="account[number][][3]">
  </div>
```

After submit i get:

```
{"id":{"13":""},"surname":{"13":"Mike"},"number":{"13":{"1":"623"},"14":{"2":"432"},"15":{"3":"542"}}}
```

But i need:

```
{"id":{"13":""},"surname":{"13":"Mike"},"number":{"13":{"1":"623","2":"432","3":"542"}}}
```

Id - Auto Increment.

Every "account[number][]" create new array. How can I put this data into an one array?

This form is added dynamically (clone).

For static form work this code, but i need dinamic:

```
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="account[surname][10]">
    <input type="text" name="account[address][10]">
    <input type="text" name="account[phone][10]">
    ...
    <input type="number" name="account[number][10][1]">
    <input type="number" name="account[number][10][2]">
    <input type="number" name="account[number][10][3]">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: How, where and when is this `id` updated? It is not in your code. And how do you clone? Put some more code in.

Comment: I have list with items and form on page. Every field on form dont have id. If i use "account[number][][54]" only 1 this field - good, but if more then 1 - bad. Clone - clone all fields on form. After submit data send to mysql database and id insert automatic. After this i can display data to page.